# Iframe doesn't work in kolkov angular editor

Tags: angular, iframe, wysiwyg, html-editor

Kolkov angular editor doesn't support Iframe.

**Package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kolkov/angular-editor**

In the editor, it looks like it's working but the front panel is not showing anything
[image: In editor looks perfect][image: Getting blank in front panel]

**Expected result is** :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For this you need to make changes in angular editor config :**
You need to set **sanitize: false**.

```
config: AngularEditorConfig = {
    sanitize: false,
  .........................
  };
```

***Due to senetize:false  chrome gives you an error in the front end like this :***

> WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).

**You can fix this error by creating custom pipe for sanitizing HTML :**

**sanitize-html.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

**In HTML**

```
<p *ngIf="appMessageData" [innerHTML]="appMessage | sanitizeHtml"></p>
```

**This will help you :)**

Comment: There is no better answer than this. Thanks!